# Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created with. Webpack and ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

I'm struggling with Webpack, Modules and Firebase. When I open the index.html It gives me the following (on the console): *Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).*

This is the code of my entry point file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { initApp } from './firebase/firebase-config.js';

initApp()
```

And the firebase-config.js:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-----",
    authDomain: "----",
    databaseURL: "---",
    projectId: "---",
    storageBucket: "---",
    messagingSenderId: "---",
    appId: "---"
};

export function initApp() {
    return firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm just calling *initializeApp* at the very beginning of my main file.

Comment: try removing the ```export ``` from ```export const```

Comment: still gives me that error.